# Is it possible to play Sleeping Dogs in a borderless window mode?

Tags: sleeping-dogs

The in-game graphics settings for Sleeping Dogs appear to be rather simplistic:

[image]

The "Fullscreen" option toggles whether the game is fullscreen or shown in a window with a border around it. Is it possible to play Sleeping Dogs in a borderless window mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [WindowedBorderlessGaming](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2675769) (name unconfirmed) to force Sleeping Dogs into borderless windowed mode. It has been tested successfully for Sleeping Dogs on Windows 7. This is also the method suggeted on [PCGamingWiki](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Sleeping_Dogs#FPS_issues_and.2For_stuttering).

Instructions from the post on Steam forums:

> 1. Run the app and start up a game.
> 2. Make sure you run the game in windowed mode before adding it to the app.
> 3. After you have set your game to run windowed, click the app's tray icon and select "Add window"
> 4. Go back to your game and while the game window is active press "F3"
> 5. Your game should now be in windowed border-less mode, your settings are saved so the app will recognize your game whenever it runs in windowed mode again and automatically set it to be borderless.